# Broken Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I tried to make a grade predictor and I had previous trouble with it. I tried to add another variable and upon deleting it, my program no longer works. When you click the button at the bottom it doesn't do anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<div id="radial-center">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="stylesheet.css">
<title>Grade Predictor</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/indexHTMLscript.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function notEmpty()
        {
            var grade1 = $('#g1').val().trim();
            var weight1 = $('#w1').val().trim();

            var grade2 = $('#g2').val().trim();
            var weight2 = $('#w2').val().trim();

            var grade3 = $('#g3').val().trim();
            var weight3 = $('#w3').val().trim();

            var grade4 = $('#g4').val().trim();
            var weight4 = $('#w4').val().trim();

            var grade5 = $('#g5').val().trim();
            var weight5 = $('#w5').val().trim();

            var grade6 = $('#g6').val().trim();
            var weight6 = $('#w6').val().trim();

            var grade7 = $('#g7').val().trim();
            var weight7 = $('#w7').val().trim();

            var grade8 = $('#g8').val().trim();
            var weight8 = $('#w8').val().trim();

            var grade9 = $('#g9').val().trim();
            var weight9 = $('#w9').val().trim();

            var grade10 = $('#g10').val().trim();
            var weight10 = $('#w10').val().trim();

            var grade11 = $('#g11').val().trim();
            var weight11 = $('#w11').val().trim();

            var grade12 = $('#g12').val().trim();
            var weight12 = $('#w12').val().trim();

            var grade13 = $('#g13').val().trim();
            var weight13 = $('#w13').val().trim();

            var grade14 = $('#g14').val().trim();
            var weight14 = $('#w14').val().trim();

            var grade15 = $('#g15').val().trim();
            var weight15 = $('#w15').val().trim();

            var grade16 = $('#g16').val().trim();
            var weight16 = $('#w16').val().trim();

            var grade17 = $('#g17').val().trim();
            var weight17 = $('#w17').val().trim();

            var grade18 = $('#g18').val().trim();
            var weight18 = $('#w18').val().trim();

            var grade19 = $('#g19').val().trim();
            var weight19 = $('#w19').val().trim();

            var grade20 = $('#g20').val().trim();
            var weight20 = $('#w20').val().trim();


            var total = 0;
            var count = 0;

            if (grade1.length > 0 && weight1.length > 0)
            {
                total += (grade1 * weight1);
                count += parseInt(weight1);
            }

            if (grade2.length > 0 && weight2.length > 0)
            {
                total += (grade2 * weight2);
                count += parseInt(weight2);
            }

            if (grade3.length > 0 && weight3.length > 0)
            {
                total += (grade3 * weight3);
                count += parseInt(weight3);
            }

            if (grade4.length > 0 && weight4.length > 0)
            {
                total += (grade4 * weight4);
                count += parseInt(weight4);
            }

            if (grade5.length > 0 && weight5.length > 0)
            {
                total += (grade5 * weight5);
                count += parseInt(weight5);
            }

            if (grade6.length > 0 && weight6.length > 0)
            {
                total += (grade6 * weight6);
                count += parseInt(weight6);
            }

            if (grade7.length > 0 && weight7.length > 0)
            {
                total += (grade7 * weight7);
                count += parseInt(weight7);
            }

            if (grade8.length > 0 && weight8.length > 0)
            {
                total += (grade8 * weight8);
                count += parseInt(weight8);
            }

            if (grade9.length > 0 && weight9.length > 0)
            {
                total += (grade9 * weight9);
                count += parseInt(weight9);
            }

            if (grade10.length > 0 && weight10.length > 0)
            {
                total += (grade10 * weight10);
                count += parseInt(weight10);
            }
            if (grade11.length > 0 && weight11.length > 0)
            {
                total += (grade11 * weight11);
                count += parseInt(weight11);
            }

            if (grade12.length > 0 && weight12.length > 0)
            {
                total += (grade12 * weight12);
                count += parseInt(weight12);
            }

            if (grade13.length > 0 && weight13.length > 0)
            {
                total += (grade13 * weight13);
                count += parseInt(weight13);
            }

            if (grade14.length > 0 && weight14.length > 0)
            {
                total += (grade14 * weight14);
                count += parseInt(weight14);
            }

            if (grade15.length > 0 && weight15.length > 0)
            {
                total += (grade15 * weight15);
                count += parseInt(weight15);
            }

            if (grade16.length > 0 && weight16.length > 0)
            {
                total += (grade16 * weight16);
                count += parseInt(weight16);
            }

            if (grade17.length > 0 && weight17.length > 0)
            {
                total += (grade17 * weight17);
                count += parseInt(weight17);
            }

            if (grade18.length > 0 && weight18.length > 0)
            {
                total += (grade18 * weight18);
                count += parseInt(weight18);
            }

            if (grade19.length > 0 && weight19.length > 0)
            {
                total += (grade19 * weight19);
                count += parseInt(weight19);
            }

            if (grade20.length > 0 && weight20.length > 0)
            {
                total += (grade20 * weight20);
                count += parseInt(weight20);
            }

            var grandTotal = Math.round(total / count);
            alert (grandTotal); 
            }
        </script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1  align="center">Grade Predictor</h1>
    <p  align="center">Enter 4, 3, 2, 1, or 0 into "Grade" slots. Enter 5, 4, 3 ,2, or 1 into "Weight" slots.</p>
<hr>
    <div align="center">
            <label for="g1"></label>Grade:<input type="number" id="g1" name="grade1">
            <label for="w1"></label>Weight:<input type="number" id="w1" name="weight1">
            <label id="t1"></label>
</div>
<div align="center">
        <label for="g2">Grade:</label><input type="number" id="g2" name="grade2">
        <label for="w2">Weight:</label><input type="number" id="w2" name="weight2">
        <label id="t2"></label>
</div>
<div align="center">
        <label for="g3">Grade:</label><input type="number" id="g3" name="grade3">
        <label for="w3">Weight:</label><input type="number" id="w3" name="weight3">
        <label id="t3"></label>
</div>
<div align="center">
        <label for="g4">Grade:</label><input type="number" id="g4" name="grade4">
        <label for="w4">Weight:</label><input type="number" id="w4" name="weight4">
        <label id="t4"></label>
</div>
<div align="center">
        <label for="g5">Grade:</label><input type="number" id="g5" name="grade5">
        <label for="w5">Weight:</label><input type="number" id="w5" name="weight5">
        <label id="t5"></label>
</div>
<div align="center">
        <label for="g6">Grade:</label><input type="number" id="g6" name="grade6">
        <label for="w6">Weight:</label><input type="number" id="w6" name="weight6">
        <label id="t6"></label>
</div>
<div align="center">
        <label for="g7">Grade:</label><input type="number" id="g7" name="grade7">
        <label for="w7">Weight:</label><input type="number" id="w7" name="weight7">
        <label id="t7"></label>
</div>
<div align="center">
        <label for="g8">Grade:</label><input type="number" id="g8" name="grade8">
        <label for="w8">Weight:</label><input type="number" id="w8" name="weight8">
        <label id="t8"></label>
</div>
<div align="center">
        <label for="g9">Grade:</label><input type="number" id="g9" name="grade9">
        <label for="w9">Weight:</label><input type="number" id="w9" name="weight9">
        <label id="t9"></label>
</div>
<div align="center">
        <label for="g10">Grade:</label><input type="number" id="g10" name="grade10">
        <label for="w10">Weight:</label><input type="number" id="w10" name="weight10">
        <label id="t10"></label>
</div>
<div align="center">
        <label for="g11">Grade:</label><input type="number" id="g11" name="grade11">
        <label for="w11">Weight:</label><input type="number" id="w11" name="weight11">
        <label id="t11"></label>
</div>
<div align="center">
        <label for="g12">Grade:</label><input type="number" id="g12" name="grade12">
        <label for="w12">Weight:</label><input type="number" id="w12" name="weight12">
        <label id="t12"></label>
</div>
<div align="center">
        <label for="g13">Grade:</label><input type="number" id="g13" name="grade13">
        <label for="w13">Weight:</label><input type="number" id="w13" name="weight13">
        <label id="t13"></label>
</div>
<div align="center">
        <label for="g14">Grade:</label><input type="number" id="g14" name="grade14">
        <label for="w14">Weight:</label><input type="number" id="w14" name="weight14">
        <label id="t14"></label>
</div>
<div align="center">
        <label for="g15">Grade:</label><input type="number" id="g15" name="grade15">
        <label for="w15">Weight:</label><input type="number" id="w15" name="weight15">
        <label id="t15"></label>
</div>
<div align="center">
        <label for="g16">Grade:</label><input type="number" id="g16" name="grade16">
        <label for="w16">Weight:</label><input type="number" id="w16" name="weight16">
        <label id="t16"></label>
</div>
<div align="center">
        <label for="g17">Grade:</label><input type="number" id="g17" name="grade17">
        <label for="w17">Weight:</label><input type="number" id="w17" name="weight17">
        <label id="t17"></label>
</div>
<div align="center">
        <label for="g18">Grade:</label><input type="number" id="g18" name="grade18">
        <label for="w18">Weight:</label><input type="number" id="w18" name="weight18">
        <label id="t18"></label>
</div>
<div align="center">
        <label for="g19">Grade:</label><input type="number" id="g19" name="grade19">
        <label for="w19">Weight:</label><input type="number" id="w19" name="weight19">
        <label id="t19"></label>
</div>
<div align="center">
        <label for="g20">Grade:</label><input type="number" id="g20" name="grade20">
        <label for="w20">Weight:</label><input type="number" id="w20" name="weight20">
        <label id="t20"></label>
</div>
<div>
    <p align="center">
    <input type='button' onclick='notEmpty()' value='Calculate Grades'/>
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</div>
```

I do not want help streamlining it to use less code, I just want to know what to do to fix it and make it output correctly.

Comment: Which web-browser are you using? We need to know if you are recieving an error, you must press F12 and click on console to see the output

Comment: Don't ever post this much code, you need to create a reduction of your problem. Also, your code is begging for a for loop, hopefully you don't think it's OK to see so many lines that look 90% the same

Comment: @lucidgold - I was just typing that .   Please check if there are any console errors, chances are just seeing the error will solve your problem , if not then add the error to your question

Comment: "I do not want help streamlining it to use less code." Best of luck to you then!

Comment: Anyway this code works http://jsfiddle.net/9Ncan/ despite it's extra low quality code.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this and I did not know what you needed. I am using Firefox. I did get an error "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: Are you sure that all of this code is relevant to your problem?
Think about creating [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or you will get many downvotes and only a few (or none) answers. People are not here to analyze code dumps for you.

Comment: You should look up arrays and loops.

Comment: I am very new to programming and I am sorry if it is low quality. I have only been writing code for a few months.

Comment: Generally I am supposed to get a whole number (4, 3, 2, or 1)

Comment: Thanks Teemu. Upon testing that solution it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in the code.

The link for the JQuery file (from Google CDN) is incorrect.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
```

It should be (Note the http:// or https:// based on your website needs)

src="**http:**//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"

Comment: Thank you very much. I tested it and it works. Sorry if I put too much code or if I seem scattered.

Comment: @Lord_Voldemort7 Please read our [SO help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), it may help you in future. If answer solved you problem you can accept it. See [why and how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).